# Pass parameter to same function and receive different date and pass it to props

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two date pickers. they pass some data to the same function (`onchange`).

```
<DatePicker 
  showTime 
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" placeholder="Start"
  onChange={this.onChange()}
/>

<DatePicker
  showTime
  format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
  placeholder="End"
  onChange={this.onChange()}
/>
```

I need to receive the different date values from them and pass it to `timerChange` but I am getting only one value. how to get both values?

```
onChange = (value, dateString) => {
  const startDate = new Date(value[0]).getTime() / 1000;
  const endDate = new Date(value[1]).getTime() / 1000;

  this.setState({
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate
  });
  this.props.timer.changeTime(startDate, endDate);
};
```

Comment: You're calling the handler instead of passing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can have Two Different IDs for the Start and End Date and you can use the value of ID to get the dates as below

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
});

var dateFinder = function() {

  $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
  $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
  console.log("Start Date : " + datepicker1.value);
  console.log("Start Date : " + datepicker2.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
  <p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
  <button type="submit" onClick="dateFinder()">Submit</button>


</body>

</html>
```